# Why is this chapter called "The Lightning Struck Tower"?

Tags: harry-potter

Chapter 27 in "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood-Prince" is called "The Lightning Struck Tower". In this chapter a certain character dies on top of a tower. The tower has the Dark Mark conjured above it. There is no mention in the chapter of the word "lightning", and the chapter has nothing to do with it. Why is this chapter called this way?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's a callback to chapter 25, where Trelawney pulls out a card - the lightning-struck tower - and proclaims that calamity is coming:

> “The headmaster has intimated that he would prefer fewer visits from me,” she said coldly. “I am not one to press my company upon those who do not value it. If Dumbledore chooses to ignore the warnings the cards show —” Her bony hand closed suddenly around Harry’s wrist. “Again and again, no matter how I lay them out —” And she pulled a card dramatically from underneath her shawls. “— the lightning-struck tower,” she whispered. “Calamity. Disaster. Coming nearer all the time...”
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 25: "The Seer Overheard"</sub>

Trelawney has apparently been predicting disaster, after pulling out her cards and this one showing up again and again. And, as it turns out, she was correct.

Comment: What does lightning have to do with disaster?

Comment: @MBEllis - It's a tarot card, used to predict the future. I'd say lightning striking is pretty disastrous, and that's Trelawney's prediction based on that card.

Comment: The Tarot card "The Tower" generally does depicted a tower struck by lightning, and the Tower is notoriously one of the most disastrous Tarot cards -- easily worse than Death, for instance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tower_(Tarot_card)

Comment: Tarot reading from 'Live and Let Die': https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVISxAcxDxU&t=5s

Comment: Incidentally, it may be worth noting that Dumbledore may in fact **not** have been ignoring her warnings. After all, he employed her precisely because he knew she had real prophetic visions. In fact, we see later that he orchestrated large parts of that 'disaster', even if he didn't plan for it to happen within Hogwarts.

Comment: @user21820: I'm unconvinced. From the previous book, we know she had been predicting the death of one student per year, and she had not yet been right. While it's possible that Dumbledore took her warnings into account, I rather imagine it was the cursed ring that caused him to engage in the orchestration you describe, as he knew that his time was limited regardless. So while he may have considered her warnings, I don't think they were the determinative factor in his decision making process.

Comment: @Kevin: Obviously many of her predictions were fabricated, but Dumbledore knew that some were real. Have you forgotten that he employed her there because she predicted Harry as the one who would defeat Voldemort, and already half her prophecy had come to pass? That is why he employed her, simply to be able to acquire whatever information she might later provide. The next clear-cut one was when she predicted Pettigrew's return to Voldemort. It makes complete sense for Dumbledore to scrutinize whatever she says just to figure out whether each bit is likely prophetic or not.

Comment: @user21820: She was not conscious of her genuine predictions. Surely Dumbledore would know the difference between her genuine prophecies and her regular predictions of doom. We don't see the school taking any precautions after she predicts Harry's death (which, again, she's been doing annually, so if they took her seriously, they ought to be looking after quite a few students "just in case").

Comment: @Kevin: She misreads the signs; for example she apparently saw a big black dog but misread it as a portent of doom. So Dumbledore presumably would listen to her and attempt to figure out what she actually saw and whether it was relevant. When she tells him that calamity is coming, it is already long after Dumbledore knew it was coming so of course he dismisses her, in the same way he dismissed Harry's suspicion of Snape.